# Where is lynx.cfg stored on mac?

Tags: macos, unix

I would like to configure my lynx installation but need the  /etc/lynx-cur/lynx.cfg.  Where is the stored on a mac?  I essentially just did.

```
brew install lynx
```

Comment: Please specify how did you install lynx? Also mention the version of macOS.

Comment: see if the command `locate lynx.cfg` helps you.

Comment: Thank you I have tried searching through finder with no luck but that is a good idea.

Comment: I'd use the `find` _command_ before I'd use `locate` because the latter depends on a database that's not built by default and will have to build to use. Use: `find / -type f -iname 'lynx.cfg' 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did

```
find /usr/local -iname lynx.cfg -print
```

(because `brew` installs stuff to `/usr/local`)

and it showed me

```
/usr/local/etc/lynx.cfg
/usr/local/Cellar/lynx/2.8.9rel.1/etc/lynx.cfg
```

Then I did

```
ls -l /usr/local/etc/lynx.cfg
```

which showed me this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 luomat admin 38 Sep  4 00:05 /usr/local/etc/lynx.cfg -> ../Cellar/lynx/2.8.9rel.1/etc/lynx.cfg
```

So I would say the answer is `/usr/local/etc/lynx.cfg`